# Custom CSS in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

So in my iPad app, i'm hoping to add a custom Twitter feed using UIWebView but wanted to use a custom CSS file

Is this possible?

if so how would i go about do it?

Cheers

Comment: So you don't control the web page's css?

Comment: No it'll be a third party website like twitter or google

Comment: Wrapping a 3rd party web page is a bit fragile because they can change the page elements at any time.  It certainly is possible, but safer if you control the source page. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forcefully inject javascript into a UIWebView at any time, modifying the underlying HTML. You can either use basic javascript or, if a library like jQuery is loaded, use it:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('.className').css('color','#f00')"];
```

You can also load entire scripts and modify, add, delete  tags -- you just have to write the javascript to accomplish the changes.

Comment: Thanks, but i've barely touched javascript/jquery, so wouldn't know where to start with writing the code, but again thanks

Comment: Do you already have a specific custom CSS file you want to use?

Comment: no but I could make one in dreamweaver if the custom cad thing is poss, all I've been doing so far was to use developer tools in chrome and add css in there

Comment: Do you have a web URL you are hitting? Post it and I'll show you the code to change one of its elements in a UIWebView.

Comment: hey it's a twitter ember widget

Answer (score 0):

You can get the DOMDocument from the webview,, and then add the css to it that way.

```
DOMDocument* domDocument=[webView mainFrameDocument];
DOMElement* styleElement=[domDocument createElement:@"style"];
[styleElement setAttribute:@"type" value:@"text/css"];
DOMText* cssText=[domDocument createTextNode:@"body{font-weight:bold;}"];
[styleElement appendChild:cssText];
DOMElement* headElement=(DOMElement*)[[domDocument getElementsByTagName:@"head"] item:0];
[headElement appendChild:styleElement];
```